# Java - I'd like to ignore an empty line when reading a file

Tags: java

This should be really really simple, but for whatever reason...

```
String line;
String question = "";
Question qObj = new Question();
line = br.readLine(); //points to where i am in the file!
if (line == null){
    System.out.println("There was no question here. ");
    System.exit(1);
} else if (line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n")) {
     // do nothing, i don't want empty lines
} else {
    question = line;
}

while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
    if (line.indexOf(LoadFromDb.ANSWER_BEGIN) == 0){
        dealWithAnswer(br, qObj);
        qObj.setQuestion(question);
        break;
    } else {
    if (!line.isEmpty()){
       question += "\n" + line.trim();
    }
}
```

If the first line the code above reads is just a blank line, then it adds the blank line to the line object, it doesn't skip it. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you show the output?

Comment: Why would you expect to skip it? Setting question to line doesn't appear to change what line is read later (if you're wanting the line to advance before it hits the while loop.

Comment: Yes, you're right MrLore. I just  came to the same conclusion. Sigh, stupid error. If you want some points, throw it in as an answer and i'll mark yeh up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding my response*, this is the kind of solution I was envisioning:

```
} else if (line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n")) {
    do {
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    while(line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n"));
    question = line;
} else {
    question = line;
}
```

Although I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

*`Setting question to line doesn't appear to change what line is read later (if you're wanting the line to advance before it hits the while loop`

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, if I understand you correctly:

```
public class BlankLine
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("blankline.txt"));
        String line;
        String question = "";
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null){
            System.out.println("There was no question here. ");
            System.exit(1);
        } else if (line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n")) {
            System.out.println("Skipped a blank line");
        } else {
            question = line;
            System.out.println("Question="+question);
        }

        // Update: added this to confirm we have skipped a line
        while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
            System.out.println("Line:"+line);
        }
    }
}
```

**input**: a text file with the first line blank, and a second line with the text "Hello World"

**output**:

```
Skipped a blank line
Line:Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

Java8

```
try(
    Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(
        Paths.get(INPUT_FILE_PATH), 
        Charset.defaultCharset())
){
    stream.map(line -> line.trim()) //Reading line
          .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty()) //Filtering empty lines
          .forEach(System.out::println); //Printing each line
} catch(Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();            
}
```