# How to skip 3 elements in a java string array and get next 3 elements

Tags: java, loops

I want to get strings of an Array separated by 3 elements. For example I need to skip 3 elements 0,1,2 and take the elements of 3,4,5. And repeat. (skip 6,7,8 and get 9,10,11) until the Array ends. How should I do it?

```
String s1[] = hh.split("\\r?\\n");
System.out.println(s1[3]);

for (int i=0;i<s1.length; i++){

}
```

Substring Output :

```
            org.springframework
            spring-jdbc
            1.0-m4

            org.apache.tomcat
            tomcat-jdbc
            7.0.19

            commons-configuration
            commons-configuration
            20030311.152757

            commons-io
            commons-io
            0.1

            org.springframework.security.oauth
            spring-security-oauth2
            2.1.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: Way too broad. Tried anything?

Comment: What is your expected output, a new array for each group of 3 or...?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes new array for each 1 group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution using the modulo operator and a single loop. No risk of IndexOutOfBounds.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i % 6 > 2) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```

You can flip the condition to `i % 6 < 3` if you instead want the first 3 of every 6 elements in the array.

EDIT: The following takes your input and puts it in a `List<String[]>` where each element contain the 3 lines.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Partition2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = ...

        try (Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(input)) {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759493/3717691
            String[] array = stream.map(line -> line.trim()).filter(line -> !line.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);

            List<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String[] tmp = new String[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                tmp[i % 3] = array[i];
                if (i % 3 == 2) {
                    results.add(tmp);
                    tmp = new String[3];
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's clean, i like this one

Comment: Last elements is not showing. Last group is after 4 elements. Any tips to fix that?

Comment: @nascar895 After looking at your original input, it looks like your intent was to get the text and remove lines with only whitespace on them? The best solution would then be to remove the whitespace-lines during parsing. Let me know if I'm right.

Comment: @Jeppe Yes would be better. Is there any way to split white spaces without using new to split

Comment: @nascar895 See my update. You can filter out empty lines when reading the file (if it originates from a file). Does it do what you intended?

Comment: @Jeppe It was coming from a string the output is which I mentioned in the question. Is there a any way to eliminate that white space during substring phase, It should be easier that way

Comment: @nascar895 See my update. Keep your regex and run your String[] through the stream. Alternatively, look here for removing empty lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123385/remove-all-empty-lines

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=3;i<s1.length;i+=6){
   for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
         s1[i+j]; // here is your element
    }
}
```

just adjust loops conditions as you might get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if arrag size is not divisible by 6

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 streams. If `s` has type `E` :

```
List<E> collect = 
    IntStream.range(0, s.length) // 0...n-1
        .filter(i -> i/3%2 == 0) // g = i/3 is the number of the group and we take one group out of to (g % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> s[i]) // take s[i]
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating the answer that Antonios gave, to make it give you your desired outcome.

```
int limit = s1.length;

if (limit > 2){
    for(int i=3; i<limit; i+=6){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(i+j > limit)
               break;
            System.out.println(s1[i+j]);
        }
    if(i+6 > limit)
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to used:

```
public static String[] getSomeThing(String[] array) {
    List<String> container = new ArrayList<>(3);
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    int fullTimes = 0;
    for (String str : array) {
        if (container.size() == 3) {
            if (++fullTimes % 2 == 0) {
                tmp.addAll(container);
            }
            container.clear();
            container.add(str);
        } else {
            container.add(str);
        }
    }
    if (fullTimes % 2 != 0) {
        tmp.addAll(container);
    }

    String[] result = new String[tmp.size()];
    tmp.toArray(result);
    return result;
}
```